# Ajax complete() in then() chain doesn't execute when expected

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having a problem with the `complete()` code in my Ajax `.then()` chain -- it doesn't execute when expected.

My Ajax function shows a Spinner on `beforeSend()` and hides it on `complete()` to show the in-progress indicator. I thought these were the endpoints I could capture to decide when to show the spinner.

```
function ajaxGetActivityId() {  

var promise = $.ajax({
    type : "post",
    dataType : "json",
    url : '/myapp/activityId',   
    data : '',
    beforeSend: function(){
        showLoading();
    },
    complete: function(){
        hideLoading();
    }        
});

    return promise; // Return a promise from this function

}
```

This function is called in the `.then()` chain as follows, by an outer function:

```
function outer() {

var promise = ajaxGetActivityId() 
            .then(function(data) {
                outerFunction2();
             });
```

The debugger shows that

1. I get to the Ajax method's `beforeSend` first and show the
   Spinner, that is correct
2. Then I get to `outerFunction2()` before
   my Ajax request is complete! At that point the spinner is still
   shown, and it shouldn't be. I thought I was guaranteed I wouldn't
   get to `outerFunction2()` until the Ajax call completed.
3. Then, at some point down the road, I get to the Ajax function's `complete()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation...

> **complete**
>   A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed).

I imagine that also includes executing *after* any other promise handlers like `then` / `done`.

I would just chain the promise resolutions one after the other. For example, remove `complete` and try

```
function ajaxGetActivityId() {
  return $.ajax({ ... })
    .then(data => {
      hideLoading()
      return data
    })
}
```

This will guarantee that the `hideLoading()` call is made before any other promise resolution handlers execute.

Comment: Yes that was it. Amazing -- but also bad for code quality, the code becomes spaghetti and now I can't encapsulate the spinner in a compact way in the Ajax functions. It's horrible that there isn't a placeholder for completion before then() downstream operations, very counterintuitive.